# Discord py - Subcommand is not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a few subcommands to my code to make everything clearer.

Unfortunately, I have the problem that certain sections of code are simply not executed.

My Code:

```py
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def server(self, ctx):

    created = ctx.guild.created_at
    x = re.search("^.*:", str(created))
    x = x.group()
    x = x[:-6]

    me = ctx.guild

    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Information about ``{ctx.guild}``", description=me.description, color = 0xf7fcfd, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

    embed.add_field(name="__Information__", value=f"**Owner:** {me.owner}\n**Name:** {me.name}\n**ID:** {me.id}\n**Region:** {me.region}\n**Created at:** {x}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="__Server Information__", value=f"**Member**: {len(me.members)}\n**Roles:** {len(me.roles)}\n**Max Emojis:** {me.emoji_limit}\n**Emojis:** {len(me.emojis)}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="__Channel Information__", value=f"**Text-Channel:** {str(len(me.text_channels))}\n**Voice-Channel:** {str(len(me.voice_channels))}\n**AFK-Channel:** ``{me.afk_channel}``\n**AFK-Timeout:** ``{me.afk_timeout}sec``")

    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.message.author.name}", icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=me.icon_url)
    embed.set_image(url=me.banner_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

# SERVER AVATAR

@server.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx):

    if not ctx.guild.icon:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Server has no avatar!", color=0xf7fcfd)
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Avatar of {ctx.guild.name}", color=0xf7fcfd)
        embed.set_image(url=ctx.guild.icon_url_as(size=1024))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

# SERVER BANNER

@server.command()
async def banner(self, ctx):

    if not ctx.guild.banner:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Server has no banner!", color=0xf7fcfd)
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Banner of {ctx.guild.name}", color=0xf7fcfd)
        embed.set_image(url=ctx.guild.banner_url_as(format='png'))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The problem is that the command **?server avatar** does not provide any output. The commands **?server** and **?server banner** work perfectly.

Am I using the subcommands incorrectly or why do I get no output?

Comment: `?server avata` doesn't work because there's no such subcommand...

Comment: Sorry, just misspelled it. I meant ``?server avatar``

Comment: You just said it works perfectly.

Comment: Corrected the whole sentence, made a mistake ^^

Comment: The code works for me, both the `avatar` and `banner` subcommands work perfectly

Comment: That is interesting. I tested the code in a new file and it works fine, but when I try the code block in the other file, the code doesn't work. Do I have to pay attention to anything when using subcommands?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't work is that I already had another command called **avatar**. The Bot would always take the command (avatar) instead the subcommand (server avatar).